# Need to convert 0-10VAC (alternating current) to 0-3.3VDC (direct current)

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, adc, ac

I am using a sensor that outputs a 0-10 VAC (alternating current) and I need to convert this signal into a signal within 0-3.3VDC (direct current) to feed into an ADC.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Is there an integrated circuit/breakout board that will take care of this conversion?

Comment: What is "0-3.3VDC" ?? If it is direct, it has to some specific value.

Comment: Mention the frequency of AC signal. You would rather use voltage dividers and feed directly to ADC

Comment: Simple resistive dividers in parallel with capacitor dividers may serve the job

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53515/converting-0-to-24v-analog-signal-to-0-to-5v-for-adc-input similar

Comment: Do you want the peak of the signal converting to dc or maybe the rms of the ac signal. Maybe something else but certainly a frequency range is needed.

Comment: Is it a humidity sensor? Did you look for it's datasheet? Often the datasheet includes typical connection schematics.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Not specifically, it can still be a DC waveform like a square waves, or just different levels of DC over a period of time. Sounds like he is just wanting to an AC voltage output converted to DC for an ADC... Though, with that being the case, I wonder why he just doesn't do a DC offset. Offset the AC signal to not be negative, then do a voltage divider to get 3.3VDC max.

Comment: @JarrodChristman The question is rather vague. In the way it is stated, any any box with zero output will satisfy it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I need to convert an AC signal (whose peak can vary from 0V to 10V) into a DC signal (and this DC signal should have a max value of 3.3V upon conversion) so I can feed into an ADC.. does that clarify the question?

Comment: @JarrodChristman Yes I want the AC voltage output to be converted to DC for an ADC!.. so, doing a DC offset and the using a voltage divider sounds like a good idea...thanks!

Comment: @Umar The frequency of the AC signal is the same as the mains frequency ~ 60Hz

Comment: @Andyaka yes, I want the peak of the signal converting to DC

Answer (score 1):

Why not an active peak detector? Something like [this](https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=y453h7) would do it, though you'll need to adjust the time constant on the output filter. This is assuming you're actually coming from the same ground, i.e. your AC wave is biased around 5V.

Answer (score 0):

If the input voltage is mains frequency and you wish a DC voltage reading, you can divide the input voltage down by about 5:1 and use a circuit such as this one [from Burr-Brown](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa068/sboa068.pdf):

[image]

Preferably use a CMOS type RRIO op-amp. R1 = R2 = (say) 100K and R3 = 49.9K.

Add an RC low pass filter afterward and buffer it to get smooth DC (and you could amplify it a bit with the buffer after filtering to get more of the range of the ADC). So only three op-amps and a few discrete parts.